# Calling function to validate post array php

Tags: php, function, email-validation

I am trying to get an post array validated by php, Scenario 2 works , Scenario 1 doesn't - when calling the function inside a loop , Please Help

Scenario 1
    // Trying to call the function in the loop

```
<form action="new_signup_form_upload.php" method="POST">
Email 1 <input type = "text" name = "email[newsignup_email1]">
Email 2 <input type = "text" name = "email[newsignup_email2]">
<input type="submit" id= "submit" name= "submit">


function validate_email(){
if ($value == "") {
echo $nameErr =  '<div id = "error_message_div">Name is required</div>';
return false;
}
else{
if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
echo $emailErr = '<div id = "error_message_div">Invalid email format</div>';
return false; 
}
}
}

foreach($_POST[email] as $key => $value){
validate_email();
}
```

Scenario 2
    // The difference here is am writing the function when inside the loop

```
<form action="new_signup_form_upload.php" method="POST">
Email 1 <input type = "text" name = "email[newsignup_email1]">
Email 2 <input type = "text" name = "email[newsignup_email2]">
<input type="submit" id= "submit" name= "submit">

foreach($_POST[email] as $key => $value){

if ($value == "") {
echo $nameErr =  '<div id = "error_message_div">Name is required</div>';
return false;
}
else{
if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
echo $emailErr = '<div id = "error_message_div">Invalid email format</div>';
return false; 
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function validate_email does not have any access to outside variables (except the really really global ones). Besides a lot of other objections to the code.. you should pass the `$value` in your foreach loop

```
function validate_email($value){
if ($value == "") {
echo $nameErr =  '<div id = "error_message_div">Name is required</div>';
return false;
}
else{
if(!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
echo $emailErr = '<div id = "error_message_div">Invalid email format</div>';
return false; 
}
}
}

foreach($_POST[email] as $key => $value){
validate_email($value);
}
```